# How to customize function call order on a specific pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of custom functions :

```
Func =[{'func':'push','col':'A'},{'func':'pull','col':'B'}]
```

```
def push : #do something
def pull : #do something
```

My dataframe :

```
id  A   B
1  23  24
2  99  88
```

I wish to do operations on this dataframe according to the list 'Func' mentioned above, in that particular order given in the list.
ie, first call function 'Push' on columnA,take that output dataframe  and then call function 'Pull' on the new dataframe.

Comment: What is your question? How to implement the body of `push`/`pull`? or how to reference and to call them?

Comment: how to reference and call them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as functions are first class citizens in python, you can put them as values in a dict,

then just iterate you list and call the function on the desired column:

**EDIT: now using `exec` to have func names as strings (see OP comment)**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[23,99], "B":[24,88]})

def push(series):
  series -= 1
def pull(series):
  series /= 2

print("before:")
print(df)

Func =[{'func':'push','col':'A'},{'func':'pull','col':'B'}]

for f in Func:
  exec('{}(df[f["col"]])'.format(f['func']))

print("after:")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
before:
    A   B
0  23  24
1  99  88
after:
    A     B
0  22  12.0
1  98  44.0
```

Comment: How do i pass push and pull as strings in the Func list?..because Func =[{'func':'push','col':'A'},{'func':'pull','col':'B'}]
is giving me an errror, str object is not callable.
Also, how do i pass arguments to these functions ?

Comment: @Anti_cse51 I edited my answer to use `exec` and have `Func` with strings, just as in you original question